# Reposync for specific packages

Tags: linux, repository

I have private Linux repositories only for my server. I am making it using createrepo and reposync. But I am not using all of packages that provided when  using command `reposync` to download package.

Is there a way to reposync specific packages so I can save my storage disk? Is it possible or not? I already searched and did not find any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another utility in `yum-utils` to download only specific packages and related dependencies called `repotrack`:

```
repotrack pkg1-name pkg2-name
```

It will actually download all of package dependencies up to basic packages.
To avoid this behavior limit repositories you want to mirror with `--repoid` switch:

```
repotrack --repoid=epel pkg1-name pkg2-name
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the man page of reposync in one centos 7 host:

```
reposync(1)

    NAME
           reposync - synchronize yum repositories to a local directory

    SYNOPSIS
           reposync [options]

    DESCRIPTION
           reposync is used to synchronize a remote yum repository to a local directory, using yum to retrieve the packages.
```

So I guess that the answer is no, you cannot cherrypick packages using reposync (but you could just download the newest only packages per repo using the --newest-only switch). createrepo is the tool for creating and maintaining your own repositories, though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As the previos response of naxto asenjo, I haven't found any option to download single rpm with reposync. You can try if yumdownloader ( https://www.linuxtechi.com/download-rpm-using-yumdownloader-centos-7-rhel-7/ ) matches your needs. It allows to download a single rpm

Comment: you can do the same with just yum (yum --downloadonly --downloaddir /path install name-of-package . That would download the package + dependencies to the destination directory of your choice without installing anything), at least in centos 7 (just tested)